# Get the root folder of the installation drive in install4j

Tags: install4j

For specific needs I would like to install some files in the root directory of the installation, for example if the installation is under C:/Program Files, so I need to set some files in C:/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but I would create a "run a script" action and parse ${installer:sys.installationDir} to get the root of that...

Comment: Thanks @skydvr for your answer, I did what you said, I used split with regex to set the variable and this the script : String installDir = context.getInstallationDirectory().getPath();
String[] split = installDir.split("\\\\+");
context.setVariable("myRootDir",split[0]+"\\");return true;